# RcppArmadillo's ability to fill matrix columns using rnorm()

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to implement an rmvrnorm function that mimics the output from mvtnorm's rmvnorm function.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat rmvrnorm_arma(int n, arma::vec mu, arma::mat sigma) {
   int ncols = sigma.n_cols;
   // works with rng?
   arma::mat Y(n,ncols);
   RNGScope scope;
   for(int i = 0; i<ncols; i++){
     // Fill a column using rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
     Y.col(i) = rnorm(n);
   }

   return arma::repmat(mu, 1, n).t() + Y * arma::chol(sigma);
}
```

I am receiving an error on the line within the loop.

Specifically, the line:

```
         Y.col(i) = rnorm(n);
```

It states:

> " rmvrnorm_arma.cpp:16:15: error: no viable overloaded '='
>
> > ```
> >  Y.col(i) = rnorm(n);
> >  ~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~ "
> > ```

I know arma has arma::randn() and I will potentially take a performance hit, however, using randn() negates R's RNG scope. I would like to be able to compare the output from this function with rmvnorm().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to help the compiler: use `as` to convert the default `Rcpp::NumericVector` object output from `rnorm` to an `arma::vec` object.

```
Y.col(i) = as<arma::vec>(rnorm(n));
```

Comment: That. Or RcppArmadillo could handle it automatically if you leverage `ARMA_EXTRA_COL_PROTO` and `ARMA_EXTRA_COL_MEAT ` to handle sugar expressions.

Comment: Handling sugar expressions there correctly would also eliminate the need for a temporary materialized `arma::vec`.

Answer (score 4):

Given how `rnorm(int)` works, i.e. it creates a `NumericVector` using [the NormGenerator__mean0__sd1](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/992f440d0376bf82d312cfe89ebac6687f2a35ff/inst/include/Rcpp/stats/random/rnorm.h#L75) class, which is just a wrapper around the `::norm_rand` function, you could use something more STL-like:

```
std::generate( Y.col(i).begin(), Y.col(i).end(), ::norm_rand ) ;
```

Or you can directly use `std::generate` on the entire matrix.

```
std::generate( Y.begin(), Y.end(), ::norm_rand ) ;
```

This skips the creation (and memory allocation) of temporary `NumericVector` and `arma::vec`. You can easily derive from this approach if you need other parameters in `rnorm` by looking how various [generators are implemented in Rcpp](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/992f440d0376bf82d312cfe89ebac6687f2a35ff/inst/include/Rcpp/stats/random/rnorm.h).

You could also use the [`imbue`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#imbue) method in armadillo:

```
Y.imbue( norm_rand ) ;
```